# How to debug the Java error "return cannot convert from java.lang.String to int"

Tags: arrays, string, file, methods

In the first method, I am getting this error:

> return cannot convert from java.lang.String to int

We were trying to solve it, but we don't know what to do. The method will a String f as a parameter representing the name of the file. The purpose of this method is to read the file and it will return a String with the content of the file.

Here is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;
public class Encryption02{
  public static void main(String[] args)throws IOException{

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter the name of the file");
    String f = input.nextLine();
    String s = " ";

    readFile(f);
    writeToFile(f,s);
  }
  public static int getUnicode(char c){
    int unicode = (int) c;
    return c;
  }
  public static int readFile(String f)throws IOException{
    Scanner input = new Scanner(new File(f));

    while(input.hasNext()){
      f = input.nextLine();
      String a= String.valueOf(f);
     return f;
    }
  }
  public static void writeToFile(String f, String s)throws IOException{
    Scanner input = new Scanner(new File(f));
    PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter(""+f+"Output.txt");
    while(input.hasNext()){
      f = input.nextLine();
      for(int i = 0; i < f.length(); i++){
        int x = f.charAt(i);
        output.println(x);
      }
      output.println();
    }
    output.close();
  }
  public static void removeLastChars(String s){
   System.out.println(s.substring(0, 4)); 
  }
}
```

Comment: So what is not working correctly - be specific.

Comment: The method int  readFile(String f). The error says that the return cannot convert from java.lang.String to int.

Comment: This question has been heavily downvoted, probably for several reasons. You have a chance to learn from these reasons so that your next question is clearer, which should ensure that it is better received. (1) Always use a useful title, which is a succinct description of your problem. (2) Always explain exactly what the error is. (3) Ask for specific help, rather than just vague "help", and try not to give readers the impression that you'd like them to do your work for you.

Comment: Sorry, this is my first time using this website. My bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to check the `readFile()` function. The `while` loop returns the value of only the first line. You also didn't assign any value in your `s` variable.

I have edited your code to let the `readFile` works. You can check it below:

Note: I have used the `StringBuilder` it is better than `String`.

```
public static void main(String[] args)throws IOException{

   Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
   System.out.println("Enter the name of the file");
   String f = input.nextLine();
   String s = " ";

   s = readFile(f); // Edited this line
   writeToFile(f,s);
}
...
public static String readFile(String f)throws IOException{ // Edited the return type
   Scanner input = new Scanner(new File(f));

   StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

   while(input.hasNext()){ // Edited the while loop
      f = input.nextLine();
      String a= String.valueOf(f);

      sb.append(a);

      if(input.hasNext())
         sb.append("\n");
      }

   return sb.toString();
 }
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I am very grateful!

Comment: @ChristianDeLuna if you found the answer helpful please accept it (click green checkbox), you get a bit of rep too.